# Sprite Nodes do not appear properly in land scape mode

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having trouble finding a way to get my sprite nodes to load in thier correct x and y cordinants while they are in landscape mode.I have already tried using viewDidLayoutSubViews and viewWillLayoutSubViews but none of these methods have worked for me.v

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the problem you are having? A common mistake is that SpriteKit uses the BOTTOM left corner of the screen as the origin (positive Y values go UP), unlike UIKit which uses the TOP left corner (positive Y values go DOWN) - so make sure your layout is taking that into account. If you are mixing SpriteKit and UIKit objects in the same scene, each will use its associated framework's coordinate system.

Is the scene presented correctly in portrait mode? Posting some code might help pinpoint the issue.